# Converting an int to char using printf

Tags: c, printf, c99

I'm just wondering if following is the right way to convert int to display it as a char

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x = 500;
   printf("%hhd\n", x);
}
```

Also, from above I wonder if I should do the following to display the value of character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char c = 'a';
   printf("%hhd\n", c);
}
```

Or would just `printf("%d\n", c);` be fine? So, basically I'm trying to output the first byte of integer through printf without any casting.

Answer (score 5):

Using `%hhd` in your first example forces a C99-compliant `printf()` to convert the `int` it is passed to a `char` before printing it.  Depending on whether your characters are signed or unsigned, you might see 244 or -12 as the value printed.  It is debatable whether this is the 'correct' way to print it; most probably not.  The normal way to print a character is with `%c`.  One issue is what is `500` supposed to represent as a character; its value is out of range (on almost all platforms) for `char`, `signed char` or `unsigned char` types.  If it is a Unicode character or other wide character value, then you probably need to use the wide-character formatting variant — `wprintf()`.

Your second example using `%c` format and a plain `char` value `'a'` is well behaved and conventional.  That will print the letter 'a'.  If you use `%hhd`, it will also work and will usually print 97 (you'd have to be on an unusual computer to get a different value).

Comment: @Johathan: I don't want to use `%c` to print the character but the value of first byte of integer.

Comment: @user963241 `x & 0xFF`? Or is bitmasking also forbidden?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, that would be one way to do it. I wonder if I could just use `printf` to handle the conversion.

Comment: Which is 'the first byte of the integer'?  Is it the MSB (most significant byte), the LSB (least significant byte), or does it depend on the endianness of the hardware (byte at lowest address in integer)?  The `%hhd` format will print the LSB (regardless of endianness).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x = 500;
   printf("%hhu\n", x);
}
```

this will print `244`.

500 = 00000001 **11110100**

244 = **11110100**

Comment: While this works, it's usually best to make it very clear what the intent of the code is. I generally am encouraged to use explicit casting rather than having printf() automatically handling the format conversion.

Comment: I should add, tools like PC-Lint will spew out errors with this.