# About conversion specifier of scanf in C

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers, length-modifiers

I have a question about conversion specifier of `scanf` in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num1;
    scanf("%hhd",&num1);
    printf("%d \n",num1);
}
```

Since I have typed `"%hhd"` as the conversion specifier in `scanf` function, when my input is "128", I expect -128 to be stored in `num1`.  But the result shows that 128 is stored in `num1`.

Why does this happen even though I have used `"%hhd"` to specify input as `char int`?

Comment: Looks like undefined behavior to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting an int to char using printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595628/converting-an-int-to-char-using-printf)

Comment: `%hhd` specifies that the pointer should be treated as "the next pointer is a pointer to a signed char or  unsigned char." This means that (if CHAR_BITS is 8, not an unreasonable assumption) that either 128 or -128 are perfectly valid results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 With `scanf()` issues: check results.  Unless the return value indicates something was written into `num1`, printing it does not reflect user input.

```
int num1;
if (scanf("%hhd",&num1) == 1) {
  printf("%d \n",num1);
}
```

Step 2: Enable compiler warnings.  Saves time.

```
if (scanf("%hhd",&num1) == 1) {
// warning: format '%hhd' expects argument of type 'signed char *', 
// but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
```

---

> Why does this happen even though I have used `"%hhd"` to specify input as char int?

This in not about integer types: `int` versus `char`.  The is about pointers: `int *` versus `signed char *`.   `"%hhd"` in `scanf()` matches a pointer: `signed char *` (or `unsigned char *` or `char *`), not an `int` nor `char`.

Code passed `&num1`, a `int *`.  Compliant code would pass a `signed char *`.

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.  C11 §7.21.6.2 13

That is it.  Code broke the rules, expected behavior does not occur.  Use the correct type.

```
signed char num1;
if (scanf("%hhd",&num1) == 1) {
  printf("%d \n",num1);
}
```

If code must save the result in an `int`:

```
int num1;
signed char ch1;
if (scanf("%hhd",&ch1) == 1) {
  num1 = ch1;
  printf("%d \n",num1);
}
```