# Structure Output are Different

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I have a homework using Structure and I think i understood the concept.
However when I executed my code, the output was different from my input.

I wanted to input 3 student infos such as name and test scores.

Here is my Structure Prototype and Array code:

```
struct StudentInfos{
    unsigned int Student_Number;
    char Student_Name[20];
    char PE;
    char Social;
    char Math;
    char Science;
    char English;
};

struct StudentInfos Student[3];
```

Here is the code where I input Datas:

```
    int Edit = 0;

    for (Edit = 0; Edit < 3; Edit++) {
        printf("Input Student Data\n\n");

        printf("Student Number：");
        scanf_s("%d", &Student[Edit].Student_Number);

        printf("Name：");
        scanf_s(" %s", Student[Edit].Student_Name, 20);

        printf("PE：");
        scanf_s(" %c", &Student[Edit].PE, 1);

        printf("Social Studies：");
        scanf_s(" %c", &Student[Edit].Social, 1);

        printf("Math：");
        scanf_s(" %c", &Student[Edit].Math, 1);

        printf("Science：");
        scanf_s(" %c", &Student[Edit].Science, 1);

        printf("English：");
        scanf_s(" %c", &Student[Edit].English, 1;
        printf("\n\n\n");
    }
```

I wanted to test my code if its running properly so,
Here is my code to show the Student[0]:

```
    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf("Student Number：%d\n", Student[0].Student_Number);
    printf("Name：%s\n", Student[0].Student_Name);
    printf("PE：%c\n", &Student[0].PE);
    printf("Social Studies：%c\n", &Student[0].Social);
    printf("Math：%c\n", &Student[0].Math);
    printf("Science：%c\n", &Student[0].Science);
    printf("English：%c\n", &Student[0].English);
```

Comment: `%s` is for strings. `%c` is for chars.

Comment: @John3136 tried that but it skips some of the scanf_s for some reason and outputs different result.

Comment: @user3121023 tried it but somehow after PE, it still skips

Comment: @user3121023 edited original post using the code you mentioned, but still no luck. I was able to input a test score for "PE" but after that it prints "Social Studies" and "Math" on the same line

Comment: @user3121023 it works! but the homework insist to not edit the structure variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my own problem. Changing:

```
scanf_s(" %c", &Student[Edit].PE, 1);
```

to

```
scanf_s("%hhd", &Student[Edit].PE);
```

and to show the result of Student[0]. Change:

```
printf("PE：%c\n", &Student[0].PE);
```

to

```
printf("PE：%hhd\n", Student[0].PE);
```

see: [Converting an int to char using printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595628/converting-an-int-to-char-using-printf)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a serious mistake

```
struct StudentInfos{
    unsigned int Student_Number;
    char Student_Name[20];
    char PE;
    char Social;
    char Math;
    char Science;
    char English;

};
```

In declaration you declared it as char and you are reading it as string ??

`scanf_s("%s", &Student[Edit].Social, 3);`

Comment: Yes, I already edited but still doesnt work .. see above

Comment: Mention output you got

Comment: for test purposes I inputted random numbers, but it only prints the first digit. For example 68, but the program only shows 6.

Comment: @syn3rgy You got to remember character stores only 1 character